# java.io.IOException: Can't find allure commandline <null>

Tags: jenkins, allure

My Jenkins master system is linux and slave system is windows.
I have set the allure commandline path in Global tool configuration and slave configuration, but when I run the job, I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception: 
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip/ip:port
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1693)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:310)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:908)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation.getMajorVersion(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:58)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.ReportBuilder.build(ReportBuilder.java:44)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:298)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:223)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
java.io.IOException: Can't find allure commandline <null>
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation$2.call(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:63)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation$2.call(AllureCommandlineInstallation.java:58)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:207)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:358)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you executed?

Answer (score 2):

my question is resolved by @vipinnambiar' answer,Thanks very much!

"On the agent configuration setting,set the Allure installation home directory(without the "bin") should resolve this issue. That worked for me."--@vipinnambiar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Wu2.png)

Comment: what should be the HOME value for jenkins ?